# Get the output of just bottleneck layer from autoencoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder, encoder

I'm new to Autoencoder. I have built a simple convolution autoencoder as shown below:

```
# ENCODER
input_img = Input(shape=(64, 64, 1))

encode1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, padding='same')(input_img) 
encode2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(encode1)
l = Flatten()(encode2)
l = Dense(100, activation='linear')(l)

# DECODER
d = Dense(1024, activation='linear')(l) 
d = Reshape((32,32,1))(d)
decode3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, padding='same')(d) 
decode4 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decode3)

model = models.Model(input_img, decode4)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Train it by providing training images
model.fit(x, y, epochs=20, batch_size=16)
```

Now after training this model, I want to get output from bottleneck layer i.e dense layer. That means if I throw array of shape (1000, 64, 64) to model, I want compressed array of shape (1000, 100).

I have tried one method as shown below, but it's giving me some error.

```
model = Model(inputs=[x], outputs=[l])
```

err:

```
ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`.
```

I have also tried some other method but that's also not working. Can someone tell me how can I get compressed array back after training the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the separate model for the `encoder`. After you train the whole system `encoder-decoder`, you can use only `encoder` for prediction. Code example:

```
# ENCODER
input_img = layers.Input(shape=(64, 64, 1))
encode1 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, padding='same')(input_img) 
encode2 = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(encode1)
l = layers.Flatten()(encode2)
encoder_output = layers.Dense(100, activation='linear')(l)

# DECODER
d = layers.Dense(1024, activation='linear')(encoder_output) 
d = layers.Reshape((32,32,1))(d)
decode3 = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, padding='same')(d) 
decode4 = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decode3)

model_encoder = Model(input_img, encoder_output)
model = Model(input_img, decode4)

model.fit(X, y, epochs=20, batch_size=16)
```

`model_encoder.predict(X)` should return a vector for each image.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the output of intermediate layer (bottleneck_layer).

```
# ENCODER
input_img = Input(shape=(64, 64, 1))

encode1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, padding='same')(input_img) 
encode2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(encode1)
l = Flatten()(encode2)
bottleneck = Dense(100, activation='linear', name='bottleneck_layer')(l)

# DECODER
d = Dense(1024, activation='linear')(bottleneck) 
d = Reshape((32,32,1))(d)
decode3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, padding='same')(d) 
decode4 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decode3)

# full model
model_full = models.Model(input_img, decode4)
model_full.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model_full.fit(x, y, epochs=20, batch_size=16)

# bottleneck model
bottleneck_output = model_full.get_layer('bottleneck_layer').output
model_bottleneck = models.Model(inputs = model_full.input, outputs = bottleneck_output)

bottleneck_predictions = model_bottleneck.predict(X_test)
```